# Find skips row or finds same row

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a portion of my Excel file (`wsPct` in code)

| Row Num | ID | Company | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 573 | 1433 | AAA | 1 |
| 574 | 1433 | BBB | 0 |
| 575 | 1433 | CCC | 0 |
| 576 | 1435 | DDD | 1 |

and a section of my VBA code

```
If IsNumeric(wsMerge.Cells(rowNum, "O").Value) Then
   ' Find ID in wsPct
   Set whereFound = wsPct.Columns("A").Find(wsMerge.Cells(rowNum, "O").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
   Do While Not whereFound Is Nothing
      ' Check for company match
      If wsPct.Cells(whereFound.Row, "B").Value = wsMerge.Cells(rowNum, "B").Value Then
         wsMerge.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value = wsPct.Cells(whereFound.Row, "C").Value
      End If
                
      ' Search for next match
      Set whereFound = Range(wsPct.Cells(whereFound.Row + 1, "A"), wsPct.Cells(numRows, "A")).Find(wsMerge.Cells(rowNum, "O").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
   Loop
End If
```

When I run this looking for ID=1433 and Company=BBB, it will initially `Find` row 573.  When it searches for the next match, it will `Find` row 575.  Thus, it never finds the correct row (574).  If I change the second `Find` to be (lose the `+1`)

```
      Set whereFound = Range(wsPct.Cells(whereFound.Row, "A"), wsPct.Cells(numRows, "A")).Find(wsMerge.Cells(rowNum, "O").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

then it will continue to `Find` row 573 (infinite loop).

How do I get it to `Find` row 574?

Comment: Look into [FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext)

Answer (score 1):

`Find()` has a bunch of parameters which determine how it works, so you have to juggle around a bit if you want to use this approach (instead of the more-typical `FindNext`), but it can work.

Here's an example:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngFind As Range, f As Range, v
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngFind = ws.Columns("a")
    
    v = 1433

    'Find always wraps back to the start of the range, so start after
    '  the last cell to ensure it starts looking in the first cell...
    Set f = rngFind.Find(v, after:=rngFind.Cells(rngFind.Cells.Count), _
                         lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
    
    Do While Not f Is Nothing
        Debug.Print f.Row
        
        Set rngFind = ws.Range(f.Offset(1, 0), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A"))
        Set f = rngFind.Find(v, after:=rngFind.Cells(rngFind.Cells.Count), _
                             lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
    
    Loop

End Sub
```